# How to make an .exe or batch file of any DOS command?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch

I always need to run

```
java -jar e:\abc.jar --boundHost -all-
```

in the command promt.

So I have to **Run** and type `cmd` , open the DOS prompt then I type/paste above command and press enter.

Can I make a executable file file on desktop so I can just double click on that file to run the command?

Comment: [It's not a DOS prompt and never has been](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/a-cli-is-not-a-dos-prompt.html), note.

Answer (score 2):

Just write that in a text file then rename the extension to .bat

Comment: you mean I just need to put this `java -jar e:\abc.jar --boundHost -all-1` in a .bat file

Comment: True, there is no special command for showing 'cmd' first.
Just write your 'code' in new text file & save it with .bat extension.

Comment: yes, @metalgear

Comment: … or to `.CMD`.

Comment: it doesn't work. it just oped dos window once

Answer (score -1):

first use a dos box if you want any source then mount a disk of that exe file
since an system that does not contain any os will support only dos and not exe or deb this need arises use this software dos box

Comment: Please re-read what was asked, as this answer doesn't make sense in the context of what was asked.